# How to move JSON fields in mass effectively?

Tags: json

I have a JSON like this:

```js
{
    "array1": [
      {
        "data": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "foo",
        },
        "classes": "class1" 
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "bar",
        },
        "classes": "class2"
       ...
      }
}
```

I want to move all the `classes` into `data` object. Using https://jsoneditoronline.org I can only do that for each object individually. I guess I can write a script to do this, but is there a built tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there will be any tool for such custom requirement. May be you can try the following script.

```
json.array1.forEach(arr => {
    arr.data['classes'] = arr.classes;
    delete arr.classes;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that regex is the quickest way to do this.  Here is how I do:

- Search: `("data".*?)(}.*?)(,"classes":.*?)}`
- Replace: `$1$3$2}`